# Php Deployment Stage Issue,

Tags: php, codeigniter, cpanel

i have site that is hosted on my Cpanel  with registered domain(ex:domain1.com project hosted here)
and have clients also and each client having different domains 
but they are not do any hosting to respective domains and it have only one htacees file that simply forward to my hosted site without changing the domain name
means 
my hosted site is : hk-test1.com/Showcase/ (i.e site hosted here)
client site is:    engineering.hk-test1.com.  (contains nothing having htacces file only that is forwarded to my hk-test1.com/Showcase/ without changing the domain or URL)

if any one enters in address bar engineering.hk-test1.com it shows content of hk-test1.com/Showcase/ means  "engineering.hk-test1.com" forwarded to "hk-test1.com/Showcase/" 
In address bar still engineering.hk-test1.com 
but my requirement is
**i have inner links in my hosted site(i.e hk-test1.com/Showcase/)means anchor tag 
when i click on that it goes to hk-test1.com/Showcase/home/theme_desc/11 this url my client url(i.e engineering.hk-test1.com/home/theme_desc/11) gone because the 
base url of my project.It is hosted at (hk-test1.com/Showcase/)
is there any posibilty like url comes with like  engineering.hk-test1.com/Showcase/home/theme_desc/11**

please help me

Comment: Not sure anyone knows what you are actually asking for? also not sure php and codeignitor are the best tags for this question...?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i changed content with clarity please look at once.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can accomplish this in cPanel by setting the base location for each sub-domain to your website root. I cannot see a useful purpose to do this, but I am sure you have your reasons. You will no longer need the .htaccess files as the sub-domain will not point to those directories any more.

When you create or edit a sub-domain (for example `engineering` or `blobby`), simply point the folder location for that sub-domain to your website root folder. That way all of the below URL'S will work.

```
hk-test1.com/Showcase/home/theme_desc/11
engineering.hk-test1.com/Showcase/home/theme_desc/11
blobby.hk-test1.com/Showcase/home/theme_desc/11
etc....
```